# VIM - prevent u from making a selection lowercase

Tags: vim, key-bindings, no-op

Often find I introduce errors when trying to yank, but accidentally press u instead of y.

I tried the below, but it doesn't help as that's targeting undo.

Is there a special way to remap keys when you have text selected?

```
    nnoremap u <Nop>
```

Comment: No, it's mostly an issue when I (very) occasionally hit u in visual mode when something selected.  I guess because I don't notice until later (compile time, etc) it is becomes an issue, while under other circumstances its immediately obvious.

Comment: You could try `vnoremap u <Nop>`

Comment: Thanks  Sergio that's the solution!  didn't know about vnoremap.

Comment: No idea why someone would mark this down, as it's a real question with a real answer.  SO is a bit snobby.

Comment: Not exactly a programming question, in my opinion. It's just "how do I use vim?".

Comment: your problem is, try pressing `y` instead of `u` to yank! you have to learn it.

Comment: No it's not.  My problem was I wanted to reassign a key.  I explained why, but if you have a problem with that I'm afraid it's actually none of your business.  I can change my editor to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is

```
xnoremap u <Nop>
```

Although it is a useful action for visual mode and has it's uses so I would instead recommend you to fix your bad habits instead of remapping this key.

Also, there's a slight difference between `vnoremap` and `xnoremap` in that when using the `v` variant (whether to map or unmap) it also does so for the special vim `SELECT` mode other than `VISUAL` mode, which has special use case, used specifically by templating libraries such as ultisnips, snipmate etc. In most cases you want to use `x` variants to apply your mappings for this reason to restrict them to apply only for `VISUAL` mode and not also for `SELECT` mode.

Comment: It's not a bad habbit.  The y and u key are right next to each other. Everyone occasionally hits the wrong key.  The difference here is that in visual mode hitting the wrong key causes a change this is often suble or not even noticable (you might not be wrapping the text, for example, and the change could happen off screen).  

So no. It's not a bad habbit.  If I inserted a u instead of a y I would notice immediately and fix the human error.

It's not a bad habbit.  If anything it's an slight drawback with vim workflow that I am trying to get around by making it less likely to happen.

Comment: While I understand your point of view, I still believe it's a case of being counter productive where you're removing a valuable functionality (visual mode `u`) to work around a human error.